# Is there any way to use function in PHP double quote string?

Tags: php, string

In JavaScript , you can do this:

```
const str = `${capitalize(name)} is cool.`;
```

Can you do the same with PHP double quote string?
Especially if the function is not a method of some instance (not calling a function pointer from variable)

This does not seem to work:

```
$str = "ucfirst($faker->word) $faker->buildingNumber";
```

Comment: The answer is no. PHP doesn't have anything analogous to JS template literals or Python F-strings.

Comment: PHP will only expand variables inside strings, not arbitrary expressions.

Comment: Use concatenation `$str = ucfirst($faker->word) . " $faker->buildingNumber";`

Comment: `$str = ucfirst($faker->word) . " {$faker->buildingNumber}"`

Comment: Yeah, I know that, and used it - I'm just curious if there was a workaround to use the double quote strings - in case you had multiple occurences in string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry, there's nothing like that built into PHP.

The [Strings documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) describes the kinds of substitutions that are done inside double-quoted strings and heredocs.

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.
>
> There are two types of syntax: a simple one and a complex one. The simple syntax is the most common and convenient. It provides a way to embed a variable, an array value, or an object property in a string with a minimum of effort.
>
> The complex syntax can be recognised by the curly braces surrounding the expression.
>   ...
>
> **Complex syntax**
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax.

Neither the simple nor complex syntax can be used to include a function call.